# Is there a more efficient way of checking whether two numbers in a list add up to an int, k?

Tags: c++, performance

I'm subscribed to a mailing list of coding challenges. This was today's:

> Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k.
>
> For example, given[10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.
>
> Bonus: Can you do this in one pass?

I came up with the following, but I was wondering if it's the most efficient solution.

```
bool found = false;
int k = 17;
list<int> given({10, 15, 3, 7});

int main() {
    for (int num : given) {
        found = find(given.begin(), given.end(), k - num) != given.end();

        if (found) break;
    }

    return found;
}
```

The code works flawlessly. I just want to know if it can be more efficient or
if I'm doing anything in my code that's frowned upon in the workplace. Many thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work flawlessly. If `k = 6` it will count `3` twice.

Comment: Even if it did work flawlessly, let's say that instead of 4 numbers, you had 1000 numbers.  Your loop will iterate 1000000 times.  Does that sound efficient?  Think outside the box, i.e. remember the numbers you've already seen in some way.

Comment: The bonus implies that it's doable in one pass and this does *n* passes.

Comment: It's doable in 1 pass if you use a a flag array of size k+1 and do exactly 0 or 2 array writes per number.

Comment: Also, if a solution to any problem involves nested `for` loops, it is almost always inefficient.   If you see yourself writing `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { for (j = 0; j < n; ++j;)` or anything equivalent to that, stop and take a different approach.

Comment: This is a classical interview problem which can be solved in linear time after sorting using the two pointers approach. Here's a good explanation of the algorithm: https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs9/sample_probs/TwoSum.pdf

Comment: @DaveS: A flag array of k+1 elements is insufficient because the problem statement does not say the numbers are non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the array once, using a set.

```
int k = 17;
list<int> given({10, 15, 3, 7});
unordered_set<int> seen();

// O(n) time-complexity
int main() {
    // Iterate over O(n) items
    for (int num : given) {
        // O(1) operations
        if (seen.contains(k - num)) {
            // seen contains a value that is the difference between k and num. If you add num to that value, k - n + n = k, you have found two numbers that sum to k
            return true;
        } else {
            // Better luck next time, keep looking
            seen.add(num);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wonder if it can count as one iteration of the array though, with a copy inside another container...

Comment: I think the focus is on the time-complexity, which would not be affected by a second pass through. But you could be right, you'd have to clarify with the challenger.

Comment: Sure, it counts. It's one iteration with O(n) memory complexity. The add and contains operations are both O(1) amortized time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster solution that has complexity O(nlogn), not sure about O(n).

Hint: Use the two-pointer method.

First sort the array.

Have two pointers - One starting from index 0 and increasing, with the other starting at the last index and decreasing.

Let the one starting from 0 be ***a*** and the one starting from the last index ***b***.

If a+b is larger than the target value, then we must decrease the index of ***b***. Remember, the numbers before index ***b*** are smaller than the number at index ***b***.

If a+b is smaller than the target value, we must increase the index of ***a***, since the numbers after index ***a*** form an increasing sequence.

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    while(b>a){
        if (v[a]+v[b]==target) {
            //There exists such values
            return 0;
        }
        else if (v[a]+v[b]>target) {
            b--;
        }
        else {
            a++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that this is not a one-pass method (as the sort itself constitutes a "superpass" of a sort), but it is at least only `O(n log n)` (with either `O(1)` or `O(n)` space overhead, depending on how your sort is implemented), where the OP's approach is `O(n²)`. For a 1000 element input, that's the difference between doing ~10,000 "units" of work and doing ~1,000,000 "units" of work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a map/dictionary of values "needed".

- Scan through given,
- Is the given value needed?

  - if yes, then done
  - else add the needed value to the needed map

Arguably, this is either O(n) or O(n log n) (depending upon map performance, and you can use a set)

pseudo-code:

```
bool searchy( int wanted ) {
    bool found = false;
    needed = map<int,bool>{};
    for( each x in given ) {
        if( needed[x] ) then { return found = true; }
        else { needed[wanted - x] = false; }
    }

    return found;
}
```

And the algorithm in C++

```
#include <map>
#include <list>
int wanted = 17;
std::list<int> given({10, 15, 3, 7});

bool searchy(int wanted) {
    bool found = false;
    std::map<int,bool> needed = {}; //could keep position of item matched...
    for (int x : given) {
        if( needed.count(x) > 0 ) { found = true; break; }
        else { needed[wanted - x] = false; }
    }
    if( found ) std::cout "found: (" << wanted - x << "+" << x << std::endl;
    return found;
}

int main() {
    bool found = searchy(wanted);
    return found;
}
```

Comment: a `std::map<Key,T>` (especially with `T = bool`) where only checking `Key` should be a `std::set<Key>`.

Comment: And yet, I may have wanted to note which position ... as that is the very next question...

Answer (score 0):

My Javascript solution using JS object (I think JS Obj serves the same as the hash map in other language). This solution memories the elements when we go through the array which can be memory expensive. But the complexity will stay as O(n).

```
const checkTwoSum = (arr, sum) => {
  const obj = {};
  const found = arr?.find(item => {
    const target = sum - item;
    if (obj[target]) return true;
    else {
        obj[item] = 1;
    }
  });

  return !!(found || found === 0);
}
```